# How do I loop across a correlation matrix to only give me pairs of correlations above a certain threshold? And/or make it more efficient

Tags: python, performance, loops, correlation

I've got the following code:

```
for i in list(corr.columns):
    for j in list(corr.columns):
        if corr.ix[i,j]>0.7 and corr.ix[i,j] != 1:
            print i, ' ',j ,' ', corr.ix[i,j]
```

The problem is that whilst this works, it returns both corr[i,j] and corr[j,i] as if they were different correlations. 
Is there anyway I could just loop through just the 'bottom triangle' of the correlation matrix?

Comment: Is your `corr` `pandas` dataframe?

Comment: yes. sorry I forgot to specify that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is one possibility, still using a loop structure similar to yours. Notice that by confining the possible value range for `j`, you eliminate much of the duplicative work from your loop. Additionally, while indexing with strings as you do might arguably make some programs more readable/robust, indexing a numpy 2d array with integers will probably prove faster (and more concise, since no `.ix` component). Indexing this way is also what allows you to skip testing elements you know you don't need.

```
# Get some toy data and extract some information from it
import pandas.io.data as pd
X = pd.DataReader('aapl','yahoo')
rows, cols = X.shape
flds = list(X.columns)

# Indexing with numbers on a numpy matrix will probably be faster
corr = X.corr().values

for i in range(cols):
    for j in range(i+1, cols):
        if corr[i,j] > 0.7:
            print flds[i], ' ', flds[j], ' ', corr[i,j]
```

Running the code above yields something like:

```
Open   High   0.99983447301
Open   Low   0.999763093885
Open   Close   0.999564997906
High   Low   0.999744241894
High   Close   0.999815965479
Low   Close   0.999794304851
```